# Hankel transfrom of $\mathrm{exp}(-r^2)/(1+r)$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, bessel-functions

I enconter a Bessel transform when I deal with a 2D hydrodynamics problem as follows:
$$H(k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{r(r+1)}+\frac{1}{r^3})e^{-a^2r^2}J_{0}(kr)rdr,$$ where $a$ is a real positive constant.

I found some results using Mathematica:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r}e^{-a^2r^2}J_{0}(kr)rdr=\frac{e^{-\frac{k^2}{8 a^2}} \sqrt{\pi} I_{0}(\frac{k^2}{8a^2})}{2a},$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^3}e^{-a^2r^2}J_{0}(kr)rdr=-\frac{e^{-\frac{k^2}{8 a^2}} \sqrt{\pi}\left(\left(4a^2+k^2\right) I_{0}(\frac{k^2}{8a^2})+k^2 I_{1}(\frac{k^2}{8a^2})\right)}{4a}.$$
But I cannot find the integral
$$H(k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r+1}e^{-a^2r^2}J_{0}(kr)rdr.$$
Any thoughts on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Neither of the integrals that you claim have closed-form results converges.  $\lim_{x\to 0}J_0(x)=J_0(0)=1$ and the integrands are $O(1/r)$ and $O(1/r^3)$ respectively as $r\to 0^+$.

Comment: while, the $\frac{1}{r(r+1)}=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}$, then the integrand should converge. I am not sure the $\frac{1}{r^3}$ term is well defined, maybe using Cauchy's principal value it is well defined.  The integrand in the last integral does not diverge at x=0.

Comment: As I wrote, neither converges.  And there is no Cauchy Principal Value interpretation.  The terms $1/r$ and $1/r^3$ cause the problem at $r=0$.

Comment: sorry, maybe I got confused. Do note that there is another "r" between $J_{0}$ and $dr$ in the integrand, so the integrand is $\frac{r}{1+r}J_{0}(kr)\mathrm{exp}(-a^2r^2)= 0$ when $x=0$.

Comment: Ah.  I missed that.  Then, only the one with $1/r^3$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. any thoughts on the last integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r+1}\mathrm{exp}(-a^2r^2)J_{0}(kr)rdr$?

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't know if this has a closed-form expression.  You might try writing the geometric series representation for $\frac1{r+1}$ and research whether there is a closed form for $\int_0^\infty r^{n}e^{-a^2r^2}J_0(kr)\,dr$.  Of course, this would leave you with an infinity series, which might or might not have a closed form.

Comment: thank you! but geometric series representation only works for $r<1$ or $r>1$ so the integral has to be broken into two pieces which may even harder to be solve.

Comment: Yes.  Indeed it does.